# Correct pronunciation of Masked

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent

In the dictionary, I saw that masked pronunciation is written as :
`/mɑːskt/` Does that mean that after saying mask, we emphasize saying `kt`?
So there should not be any sound of the letter `d` when saying `masked`?
Is that correct?

Comment: We don't _emphasize_ kt, but it IS correct to say nothing is voiced after the long vowel mɑː If the d was voiced, "masked" man would sound like "mask de_man_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not emphasised. But the pronunciation there is correct. Although the word is written with "ed", the sound is /t/.

This is usually the case with words ending in voiceless consonants Eg

- walked : /wɔːkt/
- paced : /peɪst/
- capped : /kæpt/

Be aware that this is the English /t/ and will be aspirated or not according to English rules.  Some other languages use the same letter for a subtly different sound (Eg Pinyin uses "t" for the aspirated unvoiced sound and "d" for the unvoiced unaspirated sound. In English these two sounds are the same phoneme.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. One more doubt along this lines. I found the following on the internet `These are the voiceless consonants: Ch, F, K, P, S, Sh, T, and Th`  This is confusing aren't the consonants English letters that are not vowels? Then how is `Sh` and `Th` could be consonants too? Thanks

Comment: Those are the letters and digraphs that usually represent the **voiceless** consonants   /tʃ/, /f/ /k/, /p/, /s/ /ʃ/, /t/, /θ/   You need to use phonetic symbols to represent phonemes,  For example /ʃ/ is a single consonant phoneme, but it is usually written in English by the digraph "sh".  There are also **voiced** consonants like /b/ or /d/  -- If you are Chinese, this will cause you much difficulty.